# Opencv Window disappearing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

i am hoping someone can help me this has been doing my head in for a while, i have installed opencv onto my computer following these instructions [OpenCV Turtorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Oi3HaBH8RC4)

Only differences is i add 4 files from my lib folder (opencv_world320.lib, opencv_world320d.lib, opencv_world411.lib, opencv_world411d.lib). the problem i am facing is that every time i run any code with OpenCV which uses namedWindow or imShow, my window appears for a single second then disappears even something as simple as the code below. i have tried many things and have tried many different codes however i get the same outcome. i have no idea what i am doing wrong. i am using visual studio 2017 with opencv 4.1.1. i am hoping someone can help me Thank you

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    string imageName("a.jpg"); // by default
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        imageName = argv[1];
    }

    Mat image;



    image = imread(imageName.c_str(), IMREAD_COLOR);


    if (image.empty())
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }


    namedWindow("Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    imshow("Display window", image);


    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have an `a.jpg` in the same folder as the project file.

Comment: ***Only differences is i add 4 files from my lib folder (opencv_world320.lib, opencv_world320d.lib, opencv_world411.lib, opencv_world411d.lib).*** Make sure you add only the debug libraries to your Debug configuration and only the Release libraries to your Release configuration.

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint at `return -1;`?

Comment: Hi i added all that in all configurations. i have tried return -1 to no luck. im not sure if this helps i got it to stop disappearing by using string i; cin >> i; however when the window does appear it is grey and empty. i have double checked the file location many times and it doesnt output "Could not open or find the image".

Comment: ***i added all that in all configurations.*** That part is wrong. The d.lib files are for Debug only. The others are for release only.

Comment: Hi i made those changes however still the same issue the only way to stop it so far is using cin. however again the screen is just grey

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your `a.jpg` file.

Comment: i have tried different images and the window does resize itself however its just grey

Comment: I figured it out if anyone has the same issue, here is what i did. i followed the same instructions as the youtube link however in the x64 folder of the Opencv i had vc14 and vc15, i used vc15 instead of vc14 and it worked.

Comment: That is interesting in that Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 are supposed to be binary compatible with each other.

Comment: Try cvWaitKey(0); instead of waitKey(0);   I've had similar problems before, and that's how I solved them.